# How to use ChunkedStream properly

Tags: java, netty

Here's my use case... I have an upstream service that sends my Netty app data over the network, and that data needs to be published to multiple clients connected to Netty. The data pushed to the clients must be HTTP "Transfer-Encoding: chunked."

I found `ChunkedStream` and though that maybe I could create a `PipedInputStream` and a `PipedOutputStream` (connected to the `PipedInputStream`) and write the `ChunkedStream` to the channel. Then when data is received from my upstream service I could write the data into the `PipedOutputStream` of the channels and it'd be sent to the clients:

**In channelConnected**

```
PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream(in);
ctx.getChannel().write( new PersistentChunkedStream(in) );
```

**Separate thread publishes data to a connected channels**

```
ChannelBuffer buff = ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer("FOO",CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
out.write( buff.array() );
channel.get(ChunkedWriteHandler.class).resumeTransfer();
```

I had to extend `ChunkedStream` to return `null` from `nextChunk` if there are 0 bytes available (to "suspend" the write without the thread hanging), so I call `resumeTransfer` after I write to the `PipedOutputStream` of the associated channel. When I debug and step through the code, I can see `flush`  of `ChunkedWriteHandler` being called, which does call:

```
Channels.write(ctx, writeFuture, chunk, currentEvent.getRemoteAddress());
```

with the bytes I wrote into the `PipedOutputStream,` but it's never received by the client.

**HTTP curl**

```
~ $ curl -vN http://localhost:8080/stream
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /stream HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
### NOTE: NO "FOO" TRANSMIT BACK ###
```

Any thoughts? Maybe there's a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of just before it writes "FOO" to the channel: http://screencast.com/t/XATjUfCsre6U

Note that you can see the chunk contains "70, 79, 79" = FOO

Comment: It's really strange because I can see `write0` of `NioWorker` being called and writing to the channel, but nothing on the other end. I even make sure to use "-N" of curl to prevent buffering on the client side. I've also let it run in a loop for awhile thinking something needed to be flushed, but still no dice.

Comment: It's gotta be me. I can see it in WireShark. Maybe there's a terminator I'm not passing to inform curl the chunk has been received.

Comment: I got further when I read from Wikipedia that `chunked` data must be prefixed with the number of octets, and that wasn't being included in the data sent through the ChunkedStream, so I changed "FOO" to "3\r\nFOO" and it now comes back on the client but `curl` blows up with "Received problem 3 in the chunky parser" and the connection is closed.

Comment: Mystery deepens... here's a WireShark capture of the fragment transmit http://screencast.com/t/DZ8SzYI7m. I'm not sure if the extra octets at the end are causing the problem or not.

Comment: Gebus... ok, so the extra octets were the problem. I had to NOT use the ChannelBuffer but a plain string instead like `out.write("5\r\nFOO\r\n\r\n".getBytes());` (5 = number of bytes in message = "FOO\r\n", the CRLF after the 5 and at the are per spec as delimiting the chunk length and the chunk body). Problem not really SOLVED, but I can work with it...

Comment: I can do the same with `ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer("5\r\nFOO\r\n\r\n".getBytes(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder why you even want to use the PipedInputStream / PipedOutputStream. I think it would be away cleaner / easier to just call Channel.write(..) directly without your data. Just be aware to submit as much data as you can in Channel.write(..), as its an expensive operation.

You can call Channel.write(..) from any thread that you want, as its thread-safe.

Comment: Because to chunk data, I have to pass a ChunkedInput to Channel.write(..). Currently the only implemented ChunkedInputs are for Files and Streams. Since the data I'm getting to forward to clients is not a file, and is persistent, I figured I'd try to use a stream. Then I could connect the streams and forward data from upstream to connected clients.

Comment: (continued) In my example, I have a client connected waiting for data from the server, so when the server gets some data from upstream, it needs to send it to the client (but chunked). The connection stays open, and when more data comes from upstream, it's piped to the client. I was looking for a way to intermittently send chunked data to a client with a persistent connection. (fyi, PipedInput/PipedOutputStream was just what I was using for my test case)

Comment: I know you need to send in chunks but you can do this just with Channel.write(..), just be sure you don't close the Channel before you are done with it. Channel.write(..) just write ChannelBuffers, the same is true for ChunkedInput..

Comment: So I tried a standard ChannelStream, passing in an input stream, and it didn't work. I had to extend ChannelStream to return `null` from `nextChunk` when the stream had no bytes available, and return `isEndOfInput` as null all the time...

Comment: Again, I think it would be better to directly write ChannelBuffers via Channel.write(...).  You may want to join the netty irc channel so we can talk about it in more details. I will join the channel in a few minutes

Comment: Timezones make this difficult. I'm in the channel during the day, but I'll try to be on late a few evenings and see if I can catch you.

Comment: I talked with Ryan in the irc channel. Using DefaultHttpResponse and DefaultHttpChunk is the way to go..

Comment: I had similar issues (running Netty 4.0.8), I solved it using a custom ChunkOutputStream : https://gist.github.com/codingtony/6564901 I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add some more content to the answer provided by Norman.

When sending arbitrary chunked data, you must first send a new DefaultHttpResponse (one time only):

```
HttpResponse res = new DefaultHttpResponse();
res.setChunked(true);
res.setHeader(Names.TRANSFER_ENCODING, Values.CHUNKED);
channel.write(res);
```

Then anytime you want to write to the channel with an arbitrary chunk, call:

```
HttpChunk chunk = new DefaultHttpChunk(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(str.getBytes(CharsetUtil.UTF_8)));
channel.write(chunk);
```

Comment: And don't forget to write a zero-length chunk to signal end of response to the browser: channel.write(new DefaultHttpChunk(ChannelBuffers.EMPTY_BUFFER));

Comment: Note that `.setHeader(...)` has been deprecated for some time; use `.headers().set(...)` to do the same through the `HttpHeaders` object instead

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but hopefully this helps someone.

The ChunkedStream does NOT imply HTTP Chunking...it's an unfortunate naming collision best I can tell. Chunked streams are there just to avoid loading an entire item into memory, effectively the ChunkedWriter calls back into the ChunkedStream after each chunk to ask for more data.

As it turns out, you CAN use the ChunkedStream paradigm to create something that does HTTP chunking for you from a standard input stream. The code below implements ChunkedInput and takes an InputStream. It also automatically appends the trailing http chunk to indicate EOF, but does so only once as per the ChunkedInput spec.

```
public class HttpChunkStream implements ChunkedInput {

private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 8192;
boolean eof = false;

InputStream data;

HttpChunkStream (InputStream data) {
    this.data= data;
}

byte[] buf = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
@Override
public Object nextChunk() throws Exception {
    if (eof)
        return null;        
    int b = data.read(buf);
    if (b==-1) {
        eof=true;
        return new DefaultHttpChunk(ChannelBuffers.EMPTY_BUFFER);           
    }                   
    DefaultHttpChunk c = new DefaultHttpChunk(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(buf,0,b));       
    return c;
}

@Override
public boolean isEndOfInput() throws Exception {
    return eof;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNextChunk() throws Exception {
    return isEndOfInput()==false;
}

@Override
public void close() throws Exception {
    Closeables.closeQuietly(data);              
}
```

}