# Support "Transfer-Encoding:chunked" from httpstaticfileserverhandler example

Tags: netty

I have a requirement to be able to simulate a http response with chunked encoding. Netty is the obvious choice to be able to simulate strong scalability under high load. However when a response header consists of the header

`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

the requesting client recieves the response header but never any content.

From the Netty example where it demonstrates responding to HTTPS, I changed it slightly to

```
 if (ch.getPipeline().get(SslHandler.class) != null || response.getHeader("Transfer-Encoding").equals("chunked")) 
 {
    writeFuture = ch.write(new ChunkedFile(raf, 0, fileLength, 8192));
 } else {
    use FileRegion ....
 }

 if (!isKeepAlive(req)) {
   outboundFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
 }
```

I therefore expected the chunkedFile to be handled by ChunkedWriteHandler and for the response to be sent without issue but I may be overlooking something.

The pipeline matches the handlers and order in the netty example

```
 pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
 pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(65536));
 pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
 pipeline.addLast("chunkedWriter", new ChunkedWriteHandler());

 pipeline.addLast("handler", new Handler());
```

Netty Stack Trace:

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:33)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:72)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:28)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:334)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SocketSendBufferPool$PooledSendBuffer.transferTo(SocketSendBufferPool.java:241)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.write0(AbstractNioWorker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:426)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:127)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:66)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:63)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:733)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.flush(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:276)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleDownstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:120)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:712)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:679)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:245)
    at nettyexample.Handler.messageReceived(Handler.java:93)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleUpstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:141)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkAggregator.messageReceived(HttpChunkAggregator.java:111)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:600)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:584)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:445)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:94)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:372)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:246)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.discard(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:168)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.flush(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:287)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleDownstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:120)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:712)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:679)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:245)
    at nettyexample.Handler.messageReceived(Handler.java:93)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleUpstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:141)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkAggregator.messageReceived(HttpChunkAggregator.java:111)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:600)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:584)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:445)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:94)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:372)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:246)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this thread: [How to use ChunkedStream properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027322/how-to-use-chunkedstream-properly)

To quote from the response ...

*When sending arbitrary chunked data, you must first send a new DefaultHttpResponse (one time only):*

```
HttpResponse res = new DefaultHttpResponse();
res.setChunked(true);
res.setHeader(Names.TRANSFER_ENCODING, Values.CHUNKED);
channel.write(res);
```

*Then anytime you want to write to the channel with an arbitrary chunk, call:*

```
HttpChunk chunk = new DefaultHttpChunk(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(str.getBytes(CharsetUtil.UTF_8)));
channel.write(chunk);
```

Make sure that you have `setChunked` on the `HttpResponse` object.

Comment: Great answer! just a side note that `DefaultHttpResponse` requires two constructor parameters so `new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK)` will do the job.

Comment: Note that `.setHeader(...)` has been deprecated for some time; use `.headers().set(...)` to do the same through the `HttpHeaders` object instead